# Randomly Assign Rows in Child Table to Row in Parent Table

Tags: mysql, sql

Using MySQL, I am trying to randomly assign rows in a child table to point to a row in a parent table, per following:

Parent table:  There are 50 WorkGroups (Team Alpha, Team Bravo, etc.), each of which can have a maximum number of WorkEmployees.

Child table:  There are 2,000 WorkEmployees (Ann, Bob, Carl, etc.) each of whom needs to be assigned to exactly one WorkGroup at random.

- Using MySQL Each WorkEmployee needs to be assigned to exactly one WorkGroup
- Each WorkGroup has a specified maximum number of WorkEmployees it can accommodate
- There are sufficient slots in the WorkGroups to accommodate all WorkEmployees
- I cannot used stored procedures

Following are the table structures and the UPDATE script I have developed for this purpose. The script is not working. Any guidance on what I have done wrong would be very much appreciated. Thank you.

```
CREATE TABLE WorkGroups ( ID varchar(64), GroupName varchar(64), MaxMembers int );

CREATE TABLE WorkEmployees ( ID varchar(64), EmployeeName varchar(64), WorkGroupFK varchar(64) );

  UPDATE WorkEmployees
     SET WorkGroupFK = ( SELECT WorkGroups.ID
                           FROM WorkGroups
                          WHERE ( SELECT COUNT(*) 
                                    FROM (SELECT * FROM WorkEmployees) WorkEmployees2
                                   WHERE WorkEmployees2.WorkGroupFK = WorkGroups.ID ) 
                                         < WorkGroups.MaxMembers ) /* max capacity */
   WHERE WorkEmployees.WorkGroupFK IS NULL /* employee not yet assigned */ 
   ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem besides, that it tales tome to make sample data, is that you havn't introduced the random factor and that you can only add 1 workgroup to a emplyoee

So adding a `ORDER BY RAND()` and a '`LIMIT 1` does the trick

> ```
> CREATE TABLE WorkGroups ( ID varchar(64), GroupName varchar(64), MaxMembers int );
>
> CREATE TABLE WorkEmployees ( ID varchar(64), EmployeeName varchar(64), WorkGroupFK varchar(64) );
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO WorkGroups VALUES(1,'test1',2),(2,'test1',3),(3,'test1',2)
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO WorkEmployees VALUES (1,'emp1', NULL),(2,'emp2', NULL),(3,'emp3', NULL),(4,'emp4', NULL)
> ,(5,'emp5', NULL),(6,'emp6', NULL),(7,'emp7', NULL)
> ```

> ```
>   UPDATE WorkEmployees
>      SET WorkGroupFK = ( SELECT WorkGroups.ID
>                            FROM WorkGroups
>                           WHERE ( SELECT COUNT(*) 
>                                     FROM (SELECT * FROM WorkEmployees) WorkEmployees2
>                                    WHERE WorkEmployees2.WorkGroupFK = WorkGroups.ID ) 
>                                          < WorkGroups.MaxMembers 
>                       ORDER BY RAND()
>                         LIMIT 1) /* max capacity */
>    WHERE WorkEmployees.WorkGroupFK IS NULL /* employee not yet assigned */ 
>    ;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM WorkEmployees
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | EmployeeName | WorkGroupFK
> :- | :----------- | :----------
> 1  | emp1         | 2          
> 2  | emp2         | 2          
> 3  | emp3         | 3          
> 4  | emp4         | 3          
> 5  | emp5         | 1          
> 6  | emp6         | 3          
> 7  | emp7         | 2
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f0ff7a99c78190a36092c6b0cfd26d52)*

Comment: Thank you very much - this helped tremendously, and I now see my mistakes in the original script.